Instructions per Cycle (IPC) vs Frequency
I'm working on core frequency scaling experiments and I see that with the increase in core frequency (all other stuffs untouched, for example ddr frequency is kept same), I see decrease in IPC values. Can someone explain why is it so?.
Example:
CF 1GHz, IPC is 1
CF 2GHZ, IPC is 0.95
CF 3GHZ, IPC is 0.92

Where and how are you performing these experiments? What hardware and software are you using?

I very much doubt these numbers are valid measurements in the first place, seeing how they should be way above 1, possibly even above 2, depending on the workload.

@DanielB modern processors go well beyond that, from https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instructions_per_second#Timeline_of_instructions_per_second the i5-11600k has an IPC of around 11.5 (when per core numbers are divided down - look at the "D instructions per clock cycle per core" column). Modern superscalar processors have a lot of work done to allow them to execute independent instructions simultaneously.

This is relative IPC, relative to the baseline number of 1GHz IPC.

My only assessment can be that your measurement is flawed and probably includes some (more or less) static overhead that your calculations are not accounting for. Consider this super simplified attempt to solve this:



Cycles
Flawed IPC number
Instruction count
Static overhead
“Actual” IPC




1
1
1
0.111
0.889


2
0.95
1.9
0.111
0.8945


3
0.92
2.76
0.111
0.883



…wherein “Actual IPC” is (Instruction count - Static overhead) / Cycles
That looks much more likely, doesn’t it? All this is further complicated by the fact that, unless you are performing these tests on bare metal, there’s not just your test process. This creates further complication due to not all instructions being created equal. Some require more cycles to execute and some fewer.
Maybe your method to capture the cycle counter is what introduces this static overhead.

Seems a very logical outcome :
When the core frequency (clock) goes up while all other parameters
stay the same, core speed does not change.
CPU operations then just take more time, when counted in cycles.
This means that the
instructions per cycle (IPC)
is lower.
Note that IPC is a very imprecise measure, as explained in the above
Wikipedia link.
See also the post
Why can't you have both high instructions per cycle and high clock speed?

IPC has little to do with voltage. Yes you are dealing with much higher slew rate changes in but the fact that everything can operate at 3GHz means that it can all operate at 3GHz and the voltage is irrelevant. I work in electronics and voltage is only relevant in knowing you have enough power and can go from rails to rail quickly enough. You aren't going to end up having to adjust voltage to fix problems except where one part operating faster causes a voltage drop due to power load that occurs at extreme clock speeds in modern systems well beyond 3GHz. IPC is not going to be affected.

@Mokubai: I bow before your superior knowledge, so I took the "voltage" part out. Perhaps I was thinking more in the direction of power-draw than voltage, but my electronics knowledge is spotty at best. The rest of my answer seems to me to be logical, so it's open to you to criticize anew.

Thanks makes sense. In some of the workload I see this behavior, any idea what could be doing it?. CF 1GHz, IPC is 1, CF 2GHZ, IPC is 0.95, CF 3GHZ, IPC is 0.97. IPC is increasing for higher frequency. To give more context, this is run on a perf model and ipc is relative to baseline of 1GHz.

IPC is a dummy concept, since "instructions per cycle" raises the question of "which instructions". Some very fast instructions will benefit more from a higher frequency, while others slow ones will give worse results. The figures you see are the result of some unknown internal algorithms, which I tend to view with great suspicion.

@harrymc : "Some very fast instructions will benefit more from a higher frequency" in this case we would see increase in IPC. My query is on this only. Could you tell me more on what are those fast instructions which will get benefit from higher frequency?

Nobody knows exactly which ones are included in the IPC calculations. Instructions that don't take an integral number of cycles will benefit. Theoretical example, an instruction that takes 0.8 cycle will benefit from a frequency that's 20% faster.
